# Gstreamer 0.10 on imx6 Board can't play video with audio

Tags: sound, video, gstreamer

I'm working with an imx6 board. 
I have to stream a video file, let's say a MP4 file called "video.mp4", from file to screen.
First i had some problems trying to run only the video, eventually i managed to launch and successfully watch my video on screen. 
Now i want to listen the audio of the mp4 file while watching the video, pretty standard i guess.

The problem is: when i try to listen to the audio the video just freezes on first frame and i still don't get the audio.

I've been trying a lot of pipelines for both video and audio and video/audio only.

All the pipelines that use playbin2 just freezes on first frame.

I can successfully play the video with this pipeline:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=video.mp4 ! decodebin2 ! autovideosink
```

The pipeline i use to play video with audio is:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=video.mp4 ! decodebin2 name=dec ! queue ! autovideosink dec. ! queue ! autoaudiosink
```

As i say the problem is: when i try to play video and audio with decodebin the video freezes at first frame. When i try to play video from playbin2 it still freezes. I have no idea on how to debug/solve this problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is libdvdcss installed ?! You could install the libraries like listed here : http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-play-a-dvd-in-ubuntu - then type in Ubuntu-Software-Center the search term "demuxer" and install the packages as listed there.

Comment: I have not Ubuntu-Software-Center, nor a connection to the internet through the card. Since it's really only a minimal system, i have only the Terminal. I can't use the commands apt-get. I guess i have to change the file from where ubuntu take the links for apt-get. There's not other way? I will try your solution today.

Comment: which window-manager do you use ? Do you have unity installed with dashboard ? - there is an icon looking like a little bag with an white A (this is software-center) - simply click on this icon, (type your password) and install what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of 0.10 is basically deprecated.

Second, you should use the more recent freescale [Gstreamer i.MX](https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx) plugins, made especially for video decode/sink purposes.